# Incorrect syntax near 'Name'. Must declare the scalar variable "@Provider"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hi I am using the code below to select some data and I am getting the errror Incorrect syntax near 'Name'.  Must declare the scalar variable "@Provider". Any ideas whats wrong with this? Thanks!

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = Con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NPI, [Entity Type Code], [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] FROM NPIData WHERE ([Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] LIKE @Provider Last Name (Legal Name) + '%'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provider", prefixText)
        Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read
            customers.Add(reader("@Provider").ToString)

        End While
        Con.Close()

        Return customers.ToArray
```

Comment: if you try to run the query in sql runs?

Comment: Generally avoid to create columns with spaces

Comment: convert space to _ (atleast for parameter)

Comment: You declare parameter Provider Last Name (Legal Name) in sql management studio ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code should be like this :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NPI, [Entity Type Code], [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] FROM NPIData WHERE ([Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] LIKE @Provider + '%'"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provider", prefixText)
Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read
    customers.Add(reader("[Provider Last Name (Legal Name)]").ToString)

End While
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I am getting the error Incorrect syntax near '%'.

Comment: Ok that fixed that error thank you but now on the line   customers.Add(reader("@Provider").ToString) it says index out of range?

Answer (score 1):

A parameter name/key can't include spaces.

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provide", prefixText)`

This is the syntax required.

Comment: How do I do this when the column name has spaces? Do I have to change the column names?

Comment: @user1342164 you will change parameter name , not column name

Comment: you can change parameter name as you like.. it is not compulsory to use same as column name

Comment: Ok I change the code and edited up top so you can see but now I get the error  Incorrect syntax near 'Last'.